TV show about a kid filming end editing everything that happened in his house
When I was a kid there was a show that I really liked on TV, but I can't remember its name.
It was about a little boy who had planted video cameras all over the house and the recordings were used to recreate what happened to him during the episode. The catch was that he edited these recordings before showing them so instead of seeing him being yelled at by his father, there were some cartoonish effects and sounds added (something like smoke coming out of his fathers years).
This show is probably old, since I've seen it over 10-15 years ago. It was in English, but it might not have been an US TV show.

Bailey Kipper's P.O.V.
Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey_Kipper's_P.O.V.
There was one episode where he planted a camera on his older sister to spy on her date. I remember thinking how hilariously strange it was even then.

i loved this show as a kid :)

Me too. I can't believe there was only one season!

YES! That was the show! Thanks for your answer
